# Listing Intracompany transfer on resume

Tags: internal-transfer

I'm working for a US based software solutions provider. I was initially employed (12 months) in the US office. I then requested a transfer to its subsidiary in another (my home) country. It was granted.

My job with the US Office was from 1 Feb 2019 - 31 Jan 2020. However, due to some paperwork issues, I technically joined (per contracts and stuff) on 24 Feb 2020 instead of 1 Feb 2020. The US Office and Subsidiary overseas go by the same name (they are the same organisation).

I also have a letter from the US head office stating that I was transferred to their subsidiary in Feb 2020.

On my resume, I'd like to list my employment across the two entities as a single continuous employment period.

Should I list it as a single continuous period of employment, or split it? I'd much prefer the former.

While splitting is technically accurate and by the ink, it does not capture the nature of my engagement with the company.

It would also make it look like two disparate jobs and cause an impression of job hopping

On the other hand, if I do list it as a continuous period of employment - would it raise questions during future background verifications as to whether I was truthful or not on my resume?

Answer (score 3):

Add one entry for this employer, with two sub-entries underneath, indented, which give your title and responsibilities for each position. It’s done all the time.

Comment: Yes, it's the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your resume however you want. It is an opportunity for you to showcase your skills, responsibilities and accomplishments. Whatever way looks best and says the most in the least words is the way to go.

If the positions were essentially the same in terms of responsibility and function then just list it as one job.

If the name of the company you worked under changed, you could combine them into one job and separate the names by a slash.

If your responsibilities did change, consider separating them.

If your resume is already pretty wordy, it might be a good idea to merge them for brevity sake.

If your resume is a bit sparse and you want to fill it out a bit, splitting them might be a good choice.

If you feel the duration of each one is too short and don't want to risk that reflecting badly (I doubt it would, as long as you are still working at one of them and other jobs lasted longer), then you might merge them, or list them as sub items under a single job.

It's not a matter of what you should or should not do. There is not a rule for this. Do whatever looks the best. Or better yet, do it both ways, pass them out to friends and family and ask them which they like better and why.

Comment: Any company that is worrid about a 28 day difference isn't a company I would want to work for. 
 As this answer suggests, just say you were an employee, between `Feb 2019 to Jan 2019` and `Feb 2020 to Current` which is one hundred percent truthful.  If it's a well known fact the subsidiary you now work for, is a subsidiary for the parent company, then just specify that fact on your resume.